# linear programming with $L_p$ norm constraint

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, convex-optimization, linear-programming, non-convex-optimization

$$\text{minimize } c^Tx$$
$$\text{s.t. } \|x\|_p = 1, x_i \geq 0. $$

How to derive the optimal explicit solution $x^*$? Note that $c$ is a constant vector.

Comment: Random thoughts that might be totally wrong: Hölder's inequality will show up here. I think if $c$ has at least one negative component, then $x_i = (\max\{0, -c_i\})^{q/p}$ will work. (My intuition is that for components where $c_i > 0$, one should take $x_i=0$.) The other case where $c_i \ge 0$ for all $i$ needs to be handled differently.

Comment: So how to handle if  at least one negative component? $x_i = max(0, -c_i^{q/p})$ might not the optimal one

Comment: Anyone has thoughts?

Comment: unless $p=1$ or $p=\infty$, this has little to do with linear programming (and even for those values of $p$ you need binary variables to model the equality constraint)

Comment: [this is a duplicate question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4029400/optimize-a-linear-programming-problem#comment8319256_4029400)